# Неправильный цвет при масштабировании функцией StretchBlt

Tags: winapi

Уменьшаю изображение функцией:

```
StretchBlt(HDCA,20,35, 170, 170,HDCB, 100, 100, 250, 250, SRCCOPY);
```

Изображение уменьшается, но на вид как 8 - битное, проще говоря - теряет качество цвета. В чем проблема?
Скрин, как выглядит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте поэкспериментировать с функцией [SetStretchBltMode](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Wingdi/nf-wingdi-setstretchbltmode). Ещё можно почерпнуть что-то полезное в этом [вопросе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250738/is-stretchblt-halftone-bilinear-for-all-scaling).